# Shuffle a .txt file randomly

Tags: bash, shell, text-files

I have a `.txt` file with ~800,000 e-mails that looks like this:

```
inawalton@yahoo.com
wolf2014@hotmail.com
nutnhuni24@adelphia.net
bluerebel14@aol.com
jake@vcn.com
mguillory@heincpa.com
iamderf@netzero.com
.
.
.
```

My goal is to modify this file so that it looks like this:

```
inawalton@yahoo.com, nutnhuni24@adelphia.net, wolf2014@hotmail.com, jake@vcn.com
wolf2014@hotmail.com, bluerebel14@aol.com
nutnhuni24@adelphia.net, mguillory@heincpa.com
bluerebel14@aol.com, inawalton@yahoo.com, jake@vcn.com
jake@vcn.com, bluerebel14@aol.com
mguillory@heincpa.com, iamderf@netzero.com 
iamderf@netzero.com, jake@vcn.com, bluerebel14@aol.com
.
.
.
```

What I want is to have a random amount of emails per line, separated by either commas or spaces. I didn't really want to write a program to do this, since I've heard it is possible to use certain Shell commands to do this kind of work. Is that possible and if so, how would I achieve this?

Comment: Each line of the file corresponds to a different user's list of friends. Every person has a random amount of friends.

Comment: So why not fixed 3 or 4 emails per line?

Comment: I guess I could do that, but wouldn't it be weird (from a real life point of view) that every single one of these people have exactly 4 friends? For instance, I may have 4 friends, but Bob may have 10 friends.

Comment: Aren't you helping somebody to become a **spammer**?

Comment: @chicks What do you mean?

Comment: Incorporate *shuf* and `$((RANDOM % 4 + 1))` in your program.

Comment: What is the purpose of this other than to send emails to lots of people you don't have permission to?

Comment: @chicks I am using this for a school project. I need to use a minHash to compare users (each line of the file has a corresponding user). Similar users are supposed to have the same emails in their respective lines (in the .txt file). Not sure why you would think I'd use this for something harmful/annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using awk, here's one way to do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN { srand(); } { printf $0; for (i = 0; i <= int(3 * rand()); i++) { if (getline) printf ", " $0; } print ""; }' < input.txt
```

The awk script part nicely printed and commented:

```
BEGIN {
  # initialize random seed
  srand();
}
{
  # print the next line, with terminating newline character
  printf $0;

  # loop 1 to 3 times
  for (i = 0; i <= int(3 * rand()); i++) { 
    # if we can successfully read one more line
    if (getline) {
      # print a comma and the next line
      printf ", " $0;
    }
  }

  # print a newline character to complete the line
  print "";
}
```

Comment: I do not think this is the answer to the question. He definitely want to have the emails repeated - single person can be a friend to many people. Even in the example the emails are repeated. Your script will divide file into groups of random number of emails (2 to 4 emails each). But anyway... it is accepted, so maybe I am wrong ;).

Comment: The text doesn't say anything about repeating. I see in the example output, but that might be just a sloppily written example.

Answer (score 1):

Read the emails into a bash array; loop through the array and print each element, randomly deciding to enter a newline:

```
readarray -t emails < emails.txt
for e in "${emails[@]}"
do
  printf "%s " "$e"
  [[ $((RANDOM % 10)) == 0 ]] && echo
done
echo
```

Comment: When you want some emails appear on different lines, you should first preprocess the file, duplicating addresses using $((RANDOM % 5)). Or:
read emails.txt twice and add additional addresses from the second array using random indices.

Comment: Ahhh, good point -- I missed the idea that the OP wanted some emails duplicated; my current solution shuffles the addresses into clumps, but only shows them once.